# Magento 1 : 'country_of_manufacture' product attribute Doesn't work correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

i enable **'country_of_manufacture'** product attribute in magento and set country for my products but it **doesnt** show in filter layer navigation.

**attribute setting:**

```
scope: global;
Values Required: no;
Apply To: all products type; 
Use In Layered Navigation: filterable(with result);
```

**when i change 'use in layered navigation' to filterable(no result) it show all countries in layer navigation**

i use magento 1.9.3.0

Comment: Make sure  you reindex everything product attributes @majid

Comment: how can i do that?(i am new in magento)

Comment: Go to your root project in console:-  php indexer.php --reindexall

Comment: I did but did not make any changes